# how to fix Php with Incorrect username or password display?

Tags: php

please help me fix this code 
im trying to do with incorrect username or password will display
if i put wrong data...
this code can display if i put correct data.

it will display

**Success!**

but if i put wrong nothing happens.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])):

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('login') or die ("cannot select DB");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE  username='" . $user . "' AND password='" . $pass . "'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }

        if ($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword) {
            echo '<b>Success!</b>';
        } else {
            echo ' incorrect Username or Password ';
        }

    }

endif;

?>
```

Comment: What if I used this as my password: `test" OR "a"="a`? It would accept it no matter which username is used. In other words: Your script is wide open to SQL injection! Please update it `MySQLi()` or `PDO()` and use Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in few lines.

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT userId FROM userdata WHERE  username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");


//$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
  echo "success";
}
else
  echo "Error";
```

If username & password not match query will return 0 rows.

See this article:[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thank you for this answer its working properly  .. 
i changed my code into this .. 

thnx :3

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have written the condition inside 
if($numrows!=0){
....
}

One more thing, You will always have one row returned by select query as the username should be unique for each user. So, No need of while loop there.

You were not getting anything when wrong input is entered because, the select query was not returning anything. Hence, entire if($numrows!=0) {...} was skipped.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])):

         $user=$_POST['user'];
         $pass=$_POST['pass'];

         $con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
         mysql_select_db('login') or die ("cannot select DB");

         $query=mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM userdata WHERE  username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
         $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($numrows!=0)
        {
         $dbusername=$row['username'];
         $dbpassword=$row['password'];
        }

        if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
        {
            echo'<b>Success!</b>';
        }
        else 
        {
           echo' incorrect Username or Password ';
        }
    endif;

    ?>
```

Comment: its error . . . now i cant even display the success ..
but thank you for the answer. :)