# How to fix this login form in PHP

Tags: php

Please help me.

When I input the correct username and password nothing happens If i put in an incorrect combo it outputs:

> **Invalid Username or Password..**

Please help me to fix this, here's the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Username=$_POST["user"];  //variable declaration for Username
    $Password=$_POST["pass"];  //variable declaration for Password(Encrypted)

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username1='$Username' and pasword2='$Password'";  // . this is correct dont worry about this
    $result = mysql_query($query2);  //execute query
    $host    = "localhost"; // Host name
    $db_name = "db_login";      // Database name
    $db_user = "root";      // Database user name
    $db_pass = "";      // Database Password
        // Table column from which suggestions will get shown

    $conn = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_pass)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn)or die(mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);  //no of data found
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); //rows no.
    if($row)
    {
        session_start();
        $USW=$_SESSION["username1"] = $row[2];
        $_SESSION["usertype"] = $row[4];        
        $ui=$_SESSION["Id"] = $row[0];
                                $row[4];            
    }
            $Us=$_POST['user'];
           $Up=$_POST['pass'];
      if($count == 1)  //if data found is 1
    {
        if($row[4] == "admin") //then if user type is admin
        {

            header("location:Admin/Home.php?ui=$ui");
        }
        else  //if not
        {

            header("location:user/index.php?ui=$ui");
        }
    }
    else //if data is not found or greater than 1
    {

        echo '<b style="color:red;">Invalid Username or Password</b><br>';
        echo '<b style="color:white;">Please try again..</b>';
        header("index.php");
    }
}
?>
```

help me to fix the login if the input password and username is correct

Comment: curious; is this intended for or is already a live site? I hope not

Comment: plus, you had this working http://stackoverflow.com/q/31675018/ so why the repost?

Comment: bcuz . the other one .. do not have admin and user header location..
so i changed it .. but its not working properly anymore 
thats why i repost to fix this....

Comment: use working code, make a copy of it and add to it after, don't overwrite working code. always build slowly, then when something breaks, you'll know what to go after to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: you also did not answer my first question about if this is for a live site or is intended to go live.

Comment: this is only for school project . not for live site... :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `mysql_num_rows()` call **after** the actual query:

```
$result = mysql_query($query2);  //execute query
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);  //no of data found
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); //rows no.
```

Having said that, your code makes your DB wide open for [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attacks.

Another note is that MySQL PHP module in deprecated. Consider using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Should also add a note about SQL injections and deprecated driver.

Comment: @chris85 that isn't the only thing

Comment: @chris85 Good point.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah yes, guess I should have gone further into the code.

Answer (score 0):

Execute Query only after connecting to the database

```
$result = mysql_query($query2);
```

should come after

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_pass)or die(mysql_error());
```